# Can anyone explain how to use unique( ) in the vector?

Tags: c++, sorting, unique, stdvector

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <int> v = {1, 2 , 3, 2 , 1};
    cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << v[2] << " " << v[3] << " " << v[4] << endl;
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << v[2] << " " << v[3] << " " << v[4] << endl;
    unique(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << v[2] << " " << v[3] << " " << v[4] << endl;
}
```

Output is

```
1 2 3 2 1
1 1 2 2 3
1 2 3 2 3
```

I'm not understanding what is unique function and how it is working ??

Comment: Impossible to explain it better than [std:: unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside the fact, that `bits/stdc++.h` is not the proper header when taking C++ standard into account (please use `iostream`, `vector` and `algorithm`).
From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique

> Eliminates all except the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements from the range [first, last) and **returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range**.

> **Removing is done by shifting the elements in the range in such a way that elements to be erased are overwritten**

Thus the end of the vector might contain "garbage", but this is fine, as the new end of it is also returned.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <int> v = {1, 2 , 3, 2 , 1};
    cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << v[2] << " " << v[3] << " " << v[4] << endl;
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << v[2] << " " << v[3] << " " << v[4] << endl;
    auto new_end = unique(v.begin(), v.end());
    auto b = v.begin();
    while (b!=new_end) {
        std::cout << *b++ << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xaqzE859P)

Comment: `v.erase(new_end, v.end());` might be appropriate (then for range for display :) ).